# Compare column widths of two tables in jsp

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

I'm currently including a table after making an ajax call from my main jsp.

Its coming up fine. But my question is suppose I have a table like :

```
<table id="onMainpage">
<THEAD>
<tr>
  <td> My Entries</td>
  <td> My Entries</td>
  <td> My Entries</td>
</tr>
</THEAD>
<TBODY>
<tr>
  <td> My Entries</td>
  <td> My Entries</td>
  <td> My Entries</td>
<tr>
</TBODY>
</table>
```

After making ajax call I will get the following:

```
<TBODY>
    <tr>
      <td> My Entries</td>
      <td> My Entries</td>
      <td> My Entries</td>
    <tr>
    </TBODY>
```

Point is that I will be replacing the `<TBODY>` data only and when I do that, the table is misaligned.i.e. the column length varies between THEAD and TBODY.

How can we accomplish this? Please let me know.

Comment: Why would the number of columns differ?

Comment: Number of columns does not differ.. but the data inside them is different and different lengths are present for the same.

Answer (score 1):

This could be either because u r getting different number of column or there could be empty cell in data, check in other browsers too!!

Best Solution: Fix width using CSS!!

Else:

`<td></td>` will be rendered as blank cell and if empty-cells is set to false in table property, it will reduce number of columns. Check if some data is null in server response.

Another possibility is, some unclosed tag or misaligned placement of data. Inspect Elements once u have retrieved the response.

Comment: Yes, setting the width of columns using css like:   `table.myTableClass td{width:200px;}`
BUt in case the data is big or doesnt have a space, the column width increases !!  Also a few columns do return null!!

Comment: @LearningEveryday if fixing the width still causes it to vary.. surely there is some html issue with null data, try wrap text and make empty-cells true..  u cn also chk problems for source inspection (Inspect Element or similar wat your browser provides), might be helpful. and yes, i guess the data that is load vai ajax call will not get the applied css. try jquery live or fix wiodth with style attribute of td

Comment: @LearningEveryday  oh yes.. accept the answer as corect if it works. will help others in future.. or provide comment

Comment: Thanks for the info but its not working !!  I think we are missing something here.  How to set the column width in a table, which doesn't change depending on the data it has ?

Comment: @LearningEveryday setting width attribute itself fixes the width of the column, try it on its parents.. is yr tablet and  and its poarent have fixed width? and did u try for jquery live fucntion? ajax data wnt have that css effect try <td style=""> if u rnt comfortable with jquery

Answer (score 0):

You may be adding more/less column in TBODY intialy it has other wise it should not misalign.